# Help With an (structural) Induction proof on ordered pair

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is a Structural Induction proof.

I don't want the solution, just some help in the right direction. I know normally in structural induction proofs, you use your base case, with the recursive step to get to the rest of the set, but x2 and y2 are required, so I don't know how to go about getting other elements. Also, for the actual proving, the step where we prove for an arbitrary *k*, what do you even begin with to test that *k+1* works?

I am given :

*S* is the set of ordered pairs of integers, such that:

```
    Base Step : (2,5) ∈ *S*
    Recursive Step: If (x1,x2) ∈ S and (y1,y2) ∈ S, then (x1y1,x2+y2) ∈ *S*
```

Using structural induction prove every element of *S* is of the form *(2^k,5k)*, *k* is a positive integer

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: This newsgroup is for research-level questions. Perhaps this might be more appropriate in math.stackexchange instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $S_n=\{ (2^k,5k) | k<=n \}$. Then show that $S_{n+1}$ contains only elements of the form $(2^k,5k)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a follow up question.... How can you check that they are of the same form with just the simple "assume k is some arbitrary number approach"? I feel like I am just missing a piece of information, or am just overthinking this super freakin hard. If you just throw the n in there, you would just end up with (2^n,5n) and I don't feel like that really proves anything.

Comment: you stated you didn't want the solution, but consider how many elements of $S_{n+1}$ are there